# Flask 404 when retrieving compiled css files

Tags: html, css, flask, sass

I'm currently working on styling my web app and have got some files that contain sass syntax which I'm trying to compile using the flask_assets extension, which integrates the libsass compiler into my flask application. This is the relevant piece of code on my app.py file:

```
from flask_assets import Bundle, Environment

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')
assets = Environment(app)

assets.url = app.static_url_path
assets.directory = app.static_folder

text_animation_bundle = Bundle('sass/card_text_animation.scss', filters='libsass', output='css/card_text_animation.css')
styles_bundle = Bundle('sass/style.scss', filters='libsass', output='css/style.css')

assets.register('text_animation_bundle', text_animation_bundle)
assets.register('styles_bundle', styles_bundle)
```

and on my html template:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/card_text_animation.css') }}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
```

My project folder is structured as such:

```
SENTE/
├── app.py
├── database.py
├── static/
│   ├── css/
│   │   └── (empty)
│   ├── sass/
│   │   └── (card_text_animation.scss & style.scss)
│   ├── js/
│   │   └── (js files)
│   └── (other static files)
└── templates/
    └── (index.html where I'm using the href tags mentioned above)
```

But when I execute flask run, everything is retrieved properly except these two css files that are supposed to have been compiled:

```
- - [18/Jul/2023 19:00:49] "GET /static/css/card_text_animation.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
- - [18/Jul/2023 19:00:49] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Is there anything in my setup that I'm not including? Or is there something wrong with how my folders/files are set up? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your static/css folder empty and your script does not provide you the css files you have it in your Bundle. Try installing libsass and configure it so it can help to compile,

```
pip install libsass
```